# Template being used for the "American Journal of Economics and Sociology"

Tags: templates

Do some of you have knowledge about which template that is being used for the "American Journal of Economics and Sociology"? It looks like "memoir", but there is a few tweaks.

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/ajes.12133/epdf

Comment: If this is a journal which allows submission in TeX, then it is quite likely that it provides its own class (`.cls`) file.  It may be worth looking through their submission guidelines to see if they make any references to that.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the document properties, The PDF was generated with Arbortext Advanced Print publisher (A commercially available typesetting system formerly known as 3B2) so not typeset with TeX at all.

Comment: Okay. Thank you.

But do you have knowledge about a similar latex layout? It's just for my thesis, so not for a journal submission (at least, not jet).